# Eclipse/MySQL integration plugins?

Tags: mysql, eclipse, plugins

What plugins should I install in Eclipse to integrate MySQL into Eclipse so that I can, for example, create and modify tables inside Eclipse?

Comment: You can try `Toad Extension for Eclipse` http://www.toadextensions.com that offers features for MySQL, PostgreSQL and Oracle databases.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can use any plugin which allows editing database through JDBC. You will need the MySql JDBC driver ([get it here](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/)).

There is the Eclipse own [Data Tools Project](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/) (you can get it as part of the [BIRT package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-and-report-developers/ganymedesr2)).

Two popular plugins are [DBViewer](http://www.ne.jp/asahi/zigen/home/plugin/dbviewer/about_en.html) and [Eclipse SQL Explorer](http://eclipsesql.sourceforge.net/), but there are a lot of other options. Most of [these](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewcatlink-cid-3.html) will work.

Personally, I admit, I prefer working with a native tool, I just don't like browsing the tables inside my IDE (I use [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/), which is Mac only).