# Cheap/free query tool for multi-database Java/hibernate developer

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I'm very interesting in inexpensive (better free) SQL query tool for working with multiple databases.

Generally speaking it should works with all databases which [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) supports, but it must work with Microsoft SQL Server (2000/2005/2008), Oracle (9i/10g/11g), Postgres 8.x, Sybase, Firebird, MySQL and HSQLDB.

Must have features:

- SQL code completion
- Syntax highlighting

Nice to have features:

- [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) integration
- Database specific options (like query execution plan)

Not sure if it worth to mentioned, but it will be used together with Eclipse (multiple workspaces).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My favorite is Squirrel SQL. Works well, simple to set up, nice GUI, works with all JDBC databases.

http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Come on, SQuirreL GUI needs a lot of work. But still its good.

Answer (score 2):

I really liked SQUrrel until I discovered [DBClient](https://dbclient.dev.java.net/) THere's also [DbVisualizer](http://www.minq.se/products/dbvis/) but it's not free anymore

Answer (score 1):

I'm really surprised nobody mentioned any Eclipse plugins which will fit neatly into your requirements. See [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876143/how-do-i-integrate-mysql-with-eclipse-what-plugin/). Also, [MyEclipse](http://myeclipseide.com/) recently released a cool visual query builder which you might want to check out.

Answer (score 0):

i think everyone will give you same solution, squirrel sql ,we are all using same tool =)